# Not able to make chart in NVD3. Formatting issue on x/y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am making a OHLC chart using nvd3.js. I have dataset from the API but the problem is data is not showing properly on chart. I am doing something wrong while manipulating number on axis. I have created a fiddle for the same.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9hopugn/)

[Github Link](https://github.com/abhi9419/stock-frontend)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dataSet = '{"status":"success","data":[{"key":"Open","values":[[1512432000,55.65],[1512518400,54.45],[1512604800,53.05],[1512691200,56.4],[1512950400,54.65],[1513036800,55],[1513123200,53.9],[1513209600,56],[1513296000,55.9],[1513555200,56.25]]},{"key":"High","values":[[1512432000,55.65],[1512518400,55],[1512604800,57.95],[1512691200,57],[1512950400,55.5],[1513036800,55.4],[1513123200,58.9],[1513209600,56.5],[1513296000,58.5],[1513555200,57.75]]},{"key":"Low","values":[[1512432000,53.65],[1512518400,53.1],[1512604800,53.05],[1512691200,54.1],[1512950400,54.65],[1513036800,53.7],[1513123200,53],[1513209600,54],[1513296000,55.1],[1513555200,52.5]]},{"key":"Close","values":[[1512432000,54.55],[1512518400,53.6],[1512604800,55.9],[1512691200,54.65],[1512950400,54.9],[1513036800,54.1],[1513123200,55.65],[1513209600,54.45],[1513296000,56.5],[1513555200,55.65]]}]}';

 var n = nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d[0]
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d[1]
                })
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            ;

            chart.xAxis
                .tickFormat(function (d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
                })

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(''));



            d3.select('#chart1 svg')
                .datum(JSON.parse(dataSet)['data'])
                .call(chart);


            return chart;
        });
});
```

[image]

Comment: For your fiddle to work, just remove the D3 v5 reference: https://jsfiddle.net/9cw68mmz/ Back to your question, what's the problem with this code? What do you mean by *"data is not showing properly on chart"*?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yeah i removed that, the main issue is data label on x-axis and y-axis it makes no sense with the data provided

Comment: @GerardoFurtado my dataset has values around 50 for the y axis. But in the picture you can see its going in negative and very high number on positive end

Comment: NVD3 has OHLC right out of the box thats true. I am doing something else with the chart this is just a starter. I know i am doing something silly which is very small. Not able to find it thats all

Comment: I need to check the difference i was not aware of these two but still, my x-axis is useless the date is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You want a line chart, not a cumulative line chart. Therefore, just do:

   ```
   var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
   ```
2. Your timestamp is wrong. To get the correct timestamp multiply by 1000:

   ```
   new Date(d*1000)
   ```

Here is the JSFiddle with those changes: https://jsfiddle.net/m5gef1bw/

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. Anyways thanks man really appreciate it.